# Delete confirmation with Sweetalert2 in Vue js

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, sweetalert2

I'm trying to make a sweetalert when the user clicks the delete button it will trigger a sweetalert and when the user clicks `Yes, Delete it!` it should make an axois request to delete the status. When the user clicks on `Yes, Delete it!` the sweetalert closes but the request is never made. If I remove the sweetalert and just leave the request it will delete the record.

Delete button

```
<button @click="destroy(statuses.id)" class="btn btn-danger btn-flat btn-sm"> <i class="fa fa-remove"></i> </button>
```

Delete method

```
methods: {
            destroy(id) {
                swal({
                    title: "Delete this order status?",
                    text: "Are you sure? You won't be able to revert this!",
                    type: "warning",
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    confirmButtonColor: "#3085d6",
                    confirmButtonText: "Yes, Delete it!",
                }, () => {
                    del('status-delete/' + id)
                })
            }
        }
```

Comment: can you add a `console.log(something)` inside that callback to see if that callback is being called?

Comment: did you setup Sweetalert2 by installing package or use direct Javascript source? if you installed that then you need to import it

Comment: @WreighI completely forgot about that but I just tried that and the call back is not being called. :(

Comment: @ankitpatel  i made sure to import it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based from the documentation, you can do this.

```
swal({
    title: "Delete this order status?",
    text: "Are you sure? You won't be able to revert this!",
    type: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: "#3085d6",
    confirmButtonText: "Yes, Delete it!"
}).then((result) => { // <--
    if (result.value) { // <-- if confirmed
        del('status-delete/' + id);
    }
});
```

Reference: https://sweetalert2.github.io/

Comment: cool bro, work for me

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
  swal({
     title: 'Are you sure?',
     text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
     type: 'warning',
     showCancelButton: true,
     confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
     cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
     confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
     cancelButtonText: 'No, cancel!',
     buttonsStyling: true
  }).then(function (isConfirm) {
     if(isConfirm.value === true) {
        axios.post('status-delete/'+id, {
           data: {
              id: id
           }
       }).then(function (response) {
          console.log('success')
       })
    }
  });
```